# Facebook fails w/ opengraph

Tags: metadata, facebook-opengraph

For whatever reason it looks like facebook is unable to get the OG metadata for our pages:

http://graph.facebook.com/10150555815531349

```
{
"url": "http://www.nydailynews.com/gossip/gotcha-fabulous-photos-june-21-28-gallery-1.77715",
"type": "website",
"title": "http://www.nydailynews.com/gossip/gotcha-fabulous-photos-june-21-28-gallery-1.77715",
"updated_time": "2011-12-28T19:32:54+0000",
"id": "10150555815531349"
}
```

Even though all the metadata is on the page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Gotcha! The most fabulous photos for June 21-28">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.77716!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/searchthumbnail_75/image.jpg">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="366487756153">
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I ran it thru the linter too ad it is working fine:
I used: 
http://www.nydailynews.com/gossip/gotcha-fabulous-photos-june-21-28-gallery-1.77715
on: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

And I also checked your graph link above and got different results.  **Facebook must have been caching it on you before.**

{

```
   "url": "http://www.nydailynews.com/gossip/gotcha-fabulous-photos-june-21-28-gallery-1.77715",
   "type": "article",
   "title": "Gotcha! The most fabulous photos for June 21-28",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.77716!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/searchthumbnail_75/image.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "site_name": "NY Daily News",
   "updated_time": "2011-12-29T03:00:23+0000",
   "id": "10150555815531349",
   "application": {
      "id": "366487756153",
      "name": "New York Daily News",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=366487756153"
   }
}
```